# AttributeError running python function from terminal and php exec

Tags: php, python, terminal, exec

I want to execute a function of a python class.
Oauth.py

```
import....
class Oauth:
    def __init__(self, requesttokenurl, accesstokenurl, resourceurl, version):
        .....
    def getList(self):
        .......
        return list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    .......
```

I'm testing running the command in the terminal, I tried running the following commands.
Command:

```
python -c 'import Oauth; Oauth.getList()'
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getList'
```

Command:

```
python -c 'from Oauth import *; print getList()'
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'getList' is not defined
```

Command:

```
python -c 'from Oauth import getList; print getList()'
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name getList
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
python -c 'from Oauth import Oauth; Oauth(<args>).getList()'
```

The module is called `Oauth`, so the class you are trying to use is actually `Oauth.Oauth`. You need to create an instance to call `getList()`, that's why you need to add the parentheses (and some args). The above is equivalent to the following Python program:

```
import Oauth
oa = Oauth.Oauth(<args>)
oa.getList()
```

Not sure what constructor arguments you need though.

Comment: I think you can add the script's folder to your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), but it's probably easier to [make your script executable](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable-on-unix.htm) and let the `if __name__ == '__main__'` part of the script do the `getList()` printing for you. Or you could create a separate script that only does this.

Comment: I added cd /var/www/folder/ to the command, I need to run the script from php and capture the response.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the response of André, I got this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (2 given)
```

The constructor needs 5 parameters, in this case the function does not need parameters. sending empty parameters. the command is as follows:

```
python -c 'from Oauth import Oauth; print Oauth("", "", "", "").getList()'
```